# Регулярное выражение для получения данных из url

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Всем привет. Помогите, пожалуйста написать регулярное выражение.

Есть урл: uslugi/cat-1/cat-2/cat-3/usluga-text/

Мне нужно регулярное выражение, которое будет получать "cat-1/cat-2/cat-3" (именно в таком виде) и "usluga-text" отдельно если, в урле есть слово, которое начинается с "usluga-". Если в урле нет слова, которое начинается с "usluga-", то просто возвращало "cat-1/cat-2/cat-3".

Еще раз, если такой урл (uslugi/cat-1/cat-2/cat-3/usluga-text/), то мне нужно получить:

- cat-1/cat-2/cat-3
- usluga-text

Если такой урл (uslugi/cat-1/cat-2/cat-3), то нужно получить:

- cat-1/cat-2/cat-3

Опять же этих вложенных cat-1/cat-2/... может быть любое количество, но не меньше 1.

Заранее спасибо всем, кто потратит время на мой вопрос!

Comment: Вот так - https://regex101.com/r/0CBlkj/1

Comment: Спасибо, но у вас 3-й урл регулярка не разобрала, надо чтобы вернула cat-1/cat-2/cat-3/

Comment: В конце всего поставьте вопросительный знак

Comment: Спасибо! Почти получилось. Единственное, что не совсем так, это cat-1/cat-2/cat-3/ возвращается со слешем "/" в конце. Нужно без слеша вот так cat-1/cat-2/cat-3.

Comment: я так не могу, уберите в php

Comment: Получайте результат через функцию trim().

Answer (score -1):

Получайте отдельно cat-1, cat-2, и т.д., и выполняйте преобразование в строку с разделителем `'/'`. А подстрока `usluga-text` должна быть необязательной:

```
$str = 'uslugi/cat-1/cat-2/cat-3/usluga-text/';
$cat = $service = '';

if (preg_match_all('~(cat-\d+)+/?\K(?:usluga-\pL+)?~', $str, $out)) {
    $cat = join('/', $out[1]);
    $service = $out[0][2] ?? '';
}

var_dump( $cat, $service );
```

---

Результат:

```
cat-1/cat-2/cat-3

usluga-text
```